# Java 8 streams : Combine properties of two objects which are in ArrayLists into an ArrayList of a third object type

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm new to the Java 8 streams and would appreciate some help in learning.

I have an Arraylist  of User objects and and Arraylist of UserCompany objects. The User object has a user_id and associated user information  The UserCompany list has the user's Company object but only has the user_id of the User. 
 I would like to create a third object called UserCompanyView that is a combination of the User object and the Company object using Java 8 streams. 
   I have only been able to find examples of two arrays being concatenated or merged , like,:

```
 Stream.of(list1, list2)
.flatMap(x -> x.stream())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but nothing where specific properties of the individual lists are used to create a third Object.

the code should :

1) iterate through the  UserCompany list

2)Check if the UserCompany user_id matches the User list user_id

3) if 2 is true , create a UserCompanyView object using the User and the UserCompany

4) Add the UserCompanyView  from 3 to a new List and return it.

Thanks for viewing this post and taking time to reply

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. What should happen if the user_id's do not match? And what should happen if the two lists have different sizes?

Comment: Since I am not  very experienced with the stream api yet I can only explain it  in terms of for loops.  Think of it like nested for loops where the outer loop is iterating the  UserCompany array. Then the inner loop would be iterating the User array. For each UserCompany the inner  loop will check the entire array of Users for a match. There will always be a match at some point in the inner loop's iteration because the data is set up that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they don't follow the same order, you'll need to create an ID map first:

```
Map<Integer, User> usersById = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUserId, u -> u));
```

Now you can stream the other list and map each element to its matching `User` by ID:

```
List<UserCompanyView> views = userCompanies.stream()
        .map(uc -> new UserCompanyView(usersById.get(uc.getUserId()), uc))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If there are `UserCompany`s without matching `User`s, you can filter them out by adding this before `map()`:

```
.filter(uc -> usersById.containsKey(uc.getUserId()))
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for it to perform, you start by building a `Map` of `user_id` to `User` object.

Using streams, you'd do it like this:

```
List<User> users = // built elsewhere

Map<Integer, User> userById = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUserId, u -> u));
```

Then you iterate and `UserCompany` objects, lookup the `User` object, and create the `UserCompanyView` object, adding them to a `List`.

Using streams, you'd do it like this:

```
List<UserCompany> userCompanies = // built elsewhere

List<UserCompanyView> views = userCompanies.stream()
        .map(uc -> new UserCompanyView(userById.get(uc.getUserId()), uc))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @shmosel Word-perfect code, except that `s` in `usersById`. :-)