# How to compare 2 list of objects based on date field and create a map of values present

Tags: java, date, data-structures, hashmap, treemap

So I have 2 ArrayLists (say listP, listQ) having Objects that look something like this where each object corresponds to one day of rates. These lists are result of querying a db to get data between a particular date frame ( say past 100 days). So list size can be upto 100

```
Class A{
    private Long rate1;
    private Long rate2;
    private Long timeCreated; //epoch time in seconds
    private Long vCode;
}
```

Both arraylists have same objects but are seperated by vCode (i.e listP has objects with vCode = 2 and listQ has objects with vCode =3)

My end goal is get objects from both listP and listQ for a given day (using the timeCreated field) and compare the rates between the objects from both lists for a given day based on a criteria and create a new map that has one rate object for a given date.

Points to note:

- For a given date (date derived from timeCreated field) , it is not guranteed that both lists will have an object. listP may have an object and listQ might not and viceversa.
- If for a given day, there exits an object from only listP, then I must proceed with those rates and same applies for listQ.
- It is guaranteed that the same list will have only 1 object per day.

Need some help on how I can proceed with this.

My thoughts :

I thought of creating a HashMap like map<Date, Object> . Here add all the dates present in listP and listQ and for each date, somehow map the objects from listP and listQ. Is this the right way or if there any better way to do it? How can I achieve this in code?

Comment: First, use `Instant`for time created. Under no circumstances use `Date`. Use `LocalDate` for a date. See [Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: May the same list include two or more objects for the same day (depending on time zone)?

Comment: Stream both lists, group by date and apply some method to select which rate object goes into your map. Assuming that `getTimeCreated()` returns an `Instant` as I suggested, a first shot could be `Stream.concat(listP.stream(), listQ.stream()) .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a.getTimeCreated().atZone(tz).toLocalDate(), Collectors.reducing(null, Test::compareAndSelect)))` ...

Comment: ... where `tz` is your time zone, for example `ZoneId tz = ZoneId.systemDefault();`. `Test::compareAndSelect` refers to some `private static A compareAndSelect(A one, A theOther)` that selects between two object references one of which may be null.

Comment: To answer your query, No, it is guaranteed that the same list will have only 1 object per day.

Comment: @OleV.V. How does this work for the objects that are present only in listP or listQ for a given date? In this case, I must be able to select the said object without any comparison (as there is no second object to compare with)

Comment: The way I have written the stream, if only you make sure that `compareAndSelect()` returns the non-null object when one of the arguments is null, it works the way you say. It could probably be expressed more elegantly or more clearly ... (I did run it with two lists where one of the lists was empty.)

Comment: Alternatively I think you can apply some ideas from [Java 8 streams : Combine properties of two objects which are in ArrayLists into an ArrayList of a third object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432643/java-8-streams-combine-properties-of-two-objects-which-are-in-arraylists-into).